# Change layout in Gridlayout runtime

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to change the `GridLayout` of my application in runtime, the user can select  1, 2 or 3 columns for his display. To do that I've used a `ItemDecoration` and I update the display if certains condition are met. I'm wondering if I'm not overdoing it and if there isn't a simpler or better way to do it.

Here is how it works, I have an overflow menu which asks how many column the user wants to display, this value is saved in `sharedPreferences`, by default the value is 1.
When the `fragment` is displayed, I create and populate my `RecyclerView` and then use `updateUI()` to display the datas with the correct layout.

Here is my working code:

**Adapter**

```kotlin
class HomeAdapter(private val requestManager: RequestManager,
                  private val layoutManager: GridLayoutManager? = null) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    var data: List<ImageObject> = listOf()

    enum class ViewType {
        ONE_COLUMN,
        TWO_COLUMN,
        THREE_COLUMN
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = data.size

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return when(layoutManager?.spanCount){
            2 -> ViewType.TWO_COLUMN.ordinal
            3 -> ViewType.THREE_COLUMN.ordinal
            else -> ViewType.ONE_COLUMN.ordinal
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return when (viewType) {
            ViewType.ONE_COLUMN.ordinal -> OneColumnViewHolder.from(parent)
            ViewType.TWO_COLUMN.ordinal -> TwoColumnViewHolder.from(parent)
            else -> ThreeColumnViewHolder.from(parent)
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = data[position]
        (holder as HomeViewHolder).bind(item, requestManager)
    }

    class HomeViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        private val title: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title)
        private val description: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description)
        private val imageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image)

        fun bind(imageObject: ImageObject, requestManager: RequestManager){
            title.text = imageObject.author
            description.text = imageObject.id
            requestManager.load(imageObject.url).into(imageView)
        }

    }
}

class OneColumnViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    companion object {
        fun from(parent: ViewGroup): HomeAdapter.HomeViewHolder {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_image_1c, parent, false)
            return HomeAdapter.HomeViewHolder(view)
        }
    }
}

class TwoColumnViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    companion object {
        fun from(parent: ViewGroup): HomeAdapter.HomeViewHolder {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_image_2c, parent, false)
            return HomeAdapter.HomeViewHolder(view)
        }
    }
}

class ThreeColumnViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    companion object {
        fun from(parent: ViewGroup): HomeAdapter.HomeViewHolder {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_image_3c, parent, false)
            return HomeAdapter.HomeViewHolder(view)
        }
    }
}
```

**ItemDecoration**

```kotlin
class ImageItemDecoration(private val padding: Int): RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

    override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)

        val position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)
        val totalSpanCount = getTotalSpanCount(parent)
        val spanSize = getItemSpanSize(parent, position)

        outRect.top = padding
        outRect.left = if (isFirstInRow(position, totalSpanCount, spanSize)) padding else padding / 2
        outRect.right = if (isLastInRow(position, totalSpanCount, spanSize)) padding else padding / 2
    }

    private fun isFirstInRow(position: Int, totalSpanCount: Int, spanSize: Int): Boolean {
        return if (totalSpanCount != spanSize) {
            position % totalSpanCount == 0
        } else {
            true
        }
    }

    private fun isLastInRow(position: Int, totalSpanCount: Int, spanSize: Int): Boolean =
        isFirstInRow(position + 1, totalSpanCount, spanSize)

    private fun getTotalSpanCount(parent: RecyclerView): Int =
        (parent.layoutManager as? GridLayoutManager)?.spanCount ?: 1

    private fun getItemSpanSize(parent: RecyclerView, position: Int): Int =
        (parent.layoutManager as? GridLayoutManager)?.spanSizeLookup?.getSpanSize(position) ?: 1
}
```

**MenuUtils**

```kotlin
fun updateUI(recyclerView: RecyclerView, context: Context?) {
    val sharedPreferences = context?.getSharedPreferences("GRIDLAYOUT", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val nbCol = sharedPreferences?.getInt("col", 1)!!
    val gridLayoutManager = (recyclerView.layoutManager as GridLayoutManager)

    // Set ItemDecoration
    if (nbCol > 1) {
        if (recyclerView.itemDecorationCount == 0) {
            val padding = context.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.spacing_item)
            val itemItemDecoration = ImageItemDecoration(padding)
            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemItemDecoration)
        }
        // Avoid flickering of layout if you select the same number of column again
        if(gridLayoutManager.spanCount != nbCol) {
            gridLayoutManager.spanCount = nbCol
            recyclerView.adapter?.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, recyclerView.adapter?.itemCount ?: 0)
        }
    }

    if (recyclerView.itemDecorationCount == 1 && nbCol == 1) {
        recyclerView.removeItemDecorationAt(0)
        gridLayoutManager.spanCount = nbCol
        recyclerView.adapter?.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, recyclerView.adapter?.itemCount ?: 0)

    }

}
```

Comment: Are there some significant differences between R.layout.item_image_1c and R.layout.item_image_2c?

Comment: In the end I managed to remove my 3 layout and only using one layout with `ConstraintLayout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comment I've managed to remove my 3 layout and only using one layout with `ConstraintLayout`

So I've got the following code:

**Adapter**:

```kotlin
class HomeAdapter(private val requestManager: RequestManager)
: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    var data: List<ImageObject> = listOf()

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = data.size

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return HomeViewHolder.from(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = data[position]
        (holder as HomeViewHolder).bind(item, requestManager)
    }

    class HomeViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        private val title: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title)
        private val description: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description)
        private val imageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image)

        fun bind(imageObject: ImageObject, requestManager: RequestManager){
            title.text = imageObject.author
            description.text = imageObject.id
            requestManager.load(imageObject.url).into(imageView)
        }

        companion object {
        fun from(parent: ViewGroup): HomeAdapter.HomeViewHolder {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_image, parent, false)
            return HomeAdapter.HomeViewHolder(view)
        }
    }

    }
}
```

**ItemDecoration**:

```kotlin
class ItemDecorationExoplayerVertical(private val padding: Int): RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

    override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)

        val position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)
        val totalSpanCount = getTotalSpanCount(parent)
        val column = position % totalSpanCount

        outRect.left = padding - column * padding / totalSpanCount // padding - column * ((1f / totalSpanCount) * padding)
        outRect.right = (column + 1) * padding / totalSpanCount // (column + 1) * ((1f / totalSpanCount) * padding)
        outRect.bottom = padding
        if (position < totalSpanCount) outRect.top = padding

    }

    private fun getTotalSpanCount(parent: RecyclerView): Int {
        return (parent.layoutManager as? GridLayoutManager)?.spanCount ?: 1
    }

}
```

**Utils**:

```kotlin
fun updateUI(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
    val nbCol = PreferencesHelper.readColNumber()
    val gridLayoutManager = (recyclerView.layoutManager as GridLayoutManager)
    if(gridLayoutManager.spanCount != nbCol) {
        gridLayoutManager.spanCount = nbCol
        recyclerView.adapter?.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, recyclerView.adapter?.itemCount ?: 0)
    }
}
```